# How to ignore tokens in ply.yacc

Tags: python, json, yacc, lex, ply

I'm writing a JSON configuration (i.e config file in JSON format) interpreter with PLY.

There are huge swaths of the configuration file that I'd like to ignore. Some parts that I'd like to ignore contain tokens that I can't ignore in other parts of the file.

For example, I want to ignore:

```
"features" : [{
    "name" : "someObscureFeature",
    "version": "1.2",
    "options": {
      "values" : ["a", "b", "c"]
      "allowWithoutContentLength": false,
      "enabled": true
    }
    ...
}]
```

But I do NOT want to ignore:

```
"features" : [{
    "name" : "importantFeature",        
    "version": "1.1",
    "options": {
      "value": {
        "id": 587842,
        "description": "ramy-single-hostmatch",
        "products": [
          "Fresca"
        ]
    ...
}]
```

There are also lots of other tokens within the array of features that I want to ignore if the name value is not 'importantFeature'. For example there is likely to be an array of values in both important and obscure features. I need to ignore accordingly.

Notice also that I need to extract certain elements of the `values` field and that I'd like the values field to be tokenized so I can make use of it. Effectively, I'd like to conditionally tokenize the values field if it's inside of an importantMatch.

Also note that importantFeature is just standing in for what will eventually be about a dozen different features, each with their own grammar inside of the their respective features blocks.

The problem I'm running into is that every feature, obviously, has a name. I'd like to write something along these lines:

```
def p_FEATURES(p):
    '''FEATURES : ARRAY_START FEATURE COMMA FEATURES ARRAY_END
                | ARRAY_START FEATURE ARRAY_END'''

def p_FEATURE(p):
    '''FEATURE : TESTABLE_FEATURE
               | UNTESTABLE_FEATURE'''

def p_TESTABLE_FEATURE(p):
    '''TESTABLE_FEATURE : BLOCK_START QUOTE NAME_KEY QUOTE COLON QUOTE CPCODE_FEATURE QUOTE COMMA IGNORE_KEY_VAL_PAIRS COMMA CPCODE_OPTIONS COMMA IGNORE_KEY_VAL_PAIRS'''

def p_UNTESTABLE_FEATURE(p):
    '''UNTESTABLE_FEATURE : IGNORE_BLOCK '''

def p_IGNORE_BLOCK(p):
    '''IGNORE_BLOCK : BLOCK_START LINES BLOCK_END'''
```

However the problem i'm running into is that I can't just "IGNORE_BLOCK" because the block with have  a 'name' and I have a token in my lexer called 'name':

```
def t_NAME_KEY(t): r'name'; return t
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your regex rule for parsing the value?

Comment: which value? for 'importantFeature'? that would just be: `def t_IMPORTANT_FEATURE(t): r'importantFeature'; return t`

Comment: And you have a separate rule for the unimportant one you want to ignore? Or do you not have a rule for it at all?

Comment: yeah, sort of. That's just: `
t_STRING = r'[^:^\[^\]^\{^\}^,^\"^\']+'`

Comment: I've updated my question to include a point about multiple tokens within the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a regex rule function, you can choose whether or not to return the token. Depending on what is returned, the token is either ignored or considered. For example:

```
def t_BLOCK(t):
    r'\{[\s]*name[\s]*:[\s]*(importantFeature)|(obscureFeature)\}' # will match a full block with the 'name' key in it
    if 'obscureFeature' not in t:
        return t
    else:
        pass
```

You can build a rule somewhat along these lines, and then choose whether to return the token or not based on whether your important feature was present or not.

Also, a general convention for specifying tokens to ignore as a string is to append `t_IGNORE_` to the name.

---

Based on OP's edit. Forget about elimination during tokenisation. What you could, instead do is, manually rebuild the json as you parse it with the grammar. For example.

Replace

```
def p_FEATURE(p):
    '''FEATURE : TESTABLE_FEATURE
               | UNTESTABLE_FEATURE'''

def p_TESTABLE_FEATURE(p):
    '''TESTABLE_FEATURE : BLOCK_START QUOTE NAME_KEY QUOTE COLON QUOTE CPCODE_FEATURE QUOTE COMMA IGNORE_KEY_VAL_PAIRS COMMA CPCODE_OPTIONS COMMA IGNORE_KEY_VAL_PAIRS'''

def p_UNTESTABLE_FEATURE(p):
    '''UNTESTABLE_FEATURE : IGNORE_BLOCK '''
```

with

```
data = []

def p_FEATURE(p):
    '''FEATURE : BLOCK_START DATA BLOCK_END FEATURE 
               | BLOCK_START DATA BLOCK_END'''

def p_DATA(p):
    '''DATA : KEY COLON VALUE COMMA DATA 
            | KEY COLON VALUE ''' # and so on (have another function for values)
```

What you can do now is to examine `p[2]` and see if it is important. If yes, add it to your `data` variable. Else, ignore.

This is just a rough idea. You'll still have to figure out the grammar rules exactly (for example, `VALUE` would also probably lead to another state), and adding the right blocks to `data` and how. But it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for this response but I don't think this will quite work for my case. The main reason is that I need to tokenize the block if the name-value is 'importantFeature'. I think to do this I'd have to write a regex to match on the whole block with each of the pieces inside of the feature block. This is definitely giving me some ideas but I'm not convinced this quite answers my question.

Comment: @Ramy If you can guarantee `name` is in your string, you can always use `.*` to blanket-match the rest of the string. `r'\{.*name[\s]*:[\s]*(importantFeature)|(obscureFeature)\.*}` Now that'd have to be a multiline match, since your string would contain newlines. After this, you discard or pass on the block as needed.

Comment: If you can ignore the block during tokenisation, you don't even need a rule for it.

Comment: Let me expound on my question because I think this won't work.

Comment: @Ramy Hmm, why do you feel that way? Is there something in your data that will prevent this from working?

Comment: Yes I updated my question with more information. I added more parts of the JSON data. And some notes in the two following paragraphs.

Comment: @Ramy Edited my answer.

Comment: I think between these two techniques I can get to what I need. I haven't tried this out yet but it also points towards what I'll need to actually start doing with the output (i.e. accumulating it into a data structure).

Comment: @Ramy Great to hear! Hope it works out. I take a vested interest in PLY because I've studied it in depth and even used it to write a compiler once (it had 45 grammar rules... and don't get me started on the tokenisation). I've single-handedly authored the documentation too but it hasn't gained any traction, haha.

Comment: is there any chance you could PM me your contact information? I have a feeling i'm going to need to pick your brain re lex and yacc often in the next few weeks.

Comment: @Ramy Sure, how do I PM you?

Comment: well apparently you can't (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user). I'll have to try and tag you in questions about this as I go.

Comment: @Ramy I've updated my profile with my contact info. HMU if you need me.